# C# WebAPI Top Message Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cookies, cross-domain

I have a WebAPI service that uses ADFS (not important to the question but it's microsoft's active directory authentication service).

A user sends a request to the server and since he isn't authenticated he is redirected to the ADFS's login page. Next time he sends a request to the server he will send an authentication cookie which will allow him to skip the ADFS login page.

The service is being accessed by a different domain (CORS) but I already fixed that issue. GET request are processed easily.

My problem is with OPTIONS requests, since my service is a on a different domain then the website's domain. An OPTIONS request is sent before each POST request. All OPTIONS requests do not include cookies so the request is being redirected to the ADFS login page.

I wanted to create a message handler which will execute even BEFORE the ADFS, Like a message handler that will be the very first code which will run of the message so I could check if the method of the request is OPTIONS (in which case I will simply return a response)

I tried using an example I found on message handling but it's being executed too late, the ADFS' message handler is way above it

```
public class MessageHandler2 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create the response.
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Hello!")
        };

        // Note: TaskCompletionSource creates a task that does not contain a delegate.
        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        tsc.SetResult(response);   // Also sets the task state to "RanToCompletion"
        return tsc.Task;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how can I handle a message as high up the pipe as possible? Maybe even without message handlers

Comment: take a look at this tutorial about delegating handlers http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the following tutorial...

[HTTP Message Handlers in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

You will see...

> Message handlers are called in the same order that they appear in
>   **MessageHandlers** collection. Because they are nested, the response
>   message travels in the other direction. That is, the last handler is
>   the first to get the response message.

You need to make sure you register your handler before ADFS. Take a look at your setup for your web api

Comment: Alright, HOW do I make it the first handler? at the stage of Application_Start there are no message handlers at all